# start click in UIButton, but use touchesEnded in main view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder, uibutton

I have, for example, a `UIButton` that I placed in IB.

This `UIButton` has two functions depending on whether it is just touched up inside or dragged outside - it would be nice to at least keep it functioning for touch up inside.

I want to click on my button and 'drag outside' but use `-touchesEnded` over a rectangle when I finally release my click.

I know that one option is to ditch the `UIButton` and use `-touchesBegan` over a mask, but that is a lot more effort and requires a nice big rewrite (considering the 96 buttons).

So to rephrase slightly - I've clicked on a button and held down the mouse, while dragging the cursor (/finger) over to a different point in my view and I want my view to recognise a `-touchesEnded` when I finally let go. The problem is that the initial click is tied up in the button so `-touchesEnded` in my main view doesn't happen...

Am i trying to do this the wrong way? Also, am I being clear?

EDIT: @Heckman has phrased the question well below

Comment: You wan't to know where user touched up the screen? (where touch ended instead of begined?)

Comment: pretty much yes, specifically whether it has ended up inside a cgrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are touching one button, that is contained within some UIView, and want to be able to drag your finger out, and recognize the point in the buttons superview.

Sounds to me like you should detect the button press from the button, then make a call to the `[UIButton superview]`, to tell the superview about the button pressing that started, and then handle the touch end within the view.

To notify the superview of the button that was pressed call something like (from your UIButton):

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.superview buttonPressed:self]
}
-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.superview touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

In your superview code (if you have a property buttonPressed):

```
-(void) buttonPressed:(UIButton *) button {
    _buttonPressed = button;
}
-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if(self.buttonPressed) {
         //Process the release from your drag here. 
         for(UITouch * touch in touches) {
         //Use either of these to get the release position that you care about.
             CGPoint releaseLocationInCurrentView = [touch locationInView:self];
             CGPoint releaseLocationInButtonView = [touch locationInView:[self.buttonPressed]];
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, that is a great way to phrase it, and i think my preferred option is 2), unless there is a way to record a touch event on both the button and the superview simultaneously? How would I go about 2)?

Comment: Does your app currently have a superview enclosing all of the buttons enclosed in a single view?

Comment: yep, and that's in another superview and it's that one that i'd like the click to register in. However, if your method is going to only work for the immediate superview, then I'll make it work

Comment: Here is the basics of how you would do this. I updated the answer to expand on the way that I would accomplish number 2, and what I would put for both the button and containing view touch processing. You can continue this forwarding method, or set delegates as needed to get it up to the top level view, but those should get you the general idea of what you need to accomplish.

Comment: @JamesMorris Did something about this not get you to your answer? Or why did you choose to 'unaccept' this answer. Accepting your own answer based on input from other answers seems like an odd way to do things!

Comment: haha, sorry, I don't know the site and I figured I'd tick the way that worked for me, which wasn't this way. However, I shall bow to your better judgement and accept this answer

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use a [UIPanGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on your UIView.

Here is some [example code](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/10/14/working-with-uigesturerecognizers/) for how to implement gesture recognizers.

Comment: This will be useful, thanks, but I think for a different task. I think  i'm more looking for a solution that involves registering a touchesBegan on a view simultaneously with a UIButton click - I want the button to remain where it is. I'll check this out more though, in case it is what i'm after, thanks

Comment: You may save position of the touch to class variable in UIPanGestureHandle: method and than in method TouchCancel of your button get that variable. I haven't tried, but I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something like dragable items same as iphone homescreen icons then you can have a look to TTLauncherView sample from Three20 framework. http://three20.info/showcase/launcher

Answer (score -1):

So, here's what I ended up doing, and it works quite nicely:

my UIButton on touchdragexit is assigned to an IBAction

```
-(IBAction)dragPoint:(id)sender {

//Do Something Useful in here - I assign the value to an Array that I can recall when I touch up inside one of 16 buttons

//Now pass the button touch on as a touch up outside

[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dragBegan:withEvent:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
}
```

so now I get my dragBegan like this:

```
- (void)dragBegan:(UIControl *)c withEvent:ev {

UITouch *touch = [[ev allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view]; // Get location of the moment I release the touch (touch up outside)

//now some long convoluted code to give me the location of a row of 16 buttons, of which I would like to know which one I touched up inside

UIButton *posButton;
int pos;

if(628.00<(touchPoint.y) && (touchPoint.y)<664.00){
    if ((39.00<touchPoint.x && touchPoint.x<91.00) || (92.00<touchPoint.x && touchPoint.x<144.00) || (145.00<touchPoint.x && touchPoint.x<197.00) || (198.00<touchPoint.x && touchPoint.x<250.00)||(264.00<(touchPoint.x) && touchPoint.x<314.00)||(317.00<(touchPoint.x) && touchPoint.x<367.00)||(370.00<(touchPoint.x) && touchPoint.x<420.00)||(423.00<(touchPoint.x) && touchPoint.x<473.00)||(488.00<(touchPoint.x) && touchPoint.x<538.00) || (541.00<(touchPoint.x) && touchPoint.x<591.00) || (594.00<(touchPoint.x) && touchPoint.x<644.00) || (647.00<(touchPoint.x) && touchPoint.x<697.00)||(712.00<(touchPoint.x) && touchPoint.x<762.00)||(765.00<(touchPoint.x) && touchPoint.x<815.00)||(818.00<(touchPoint.x) && touchPoint.x<868.00)||(871.00<(touchPoint.x) && touchPoint.x<921.00)){


    if(39.00<(touchPoint.x) && touchPoint.x<91.00){
        posButton = SeqA;
        pos=0;

    }
    else if(92.00<(touchPoint.x) && touchPoint.x<144.00){
        posButton = SeqB;
        pos=1;

    }
    else if(145.00<(touchPoint.x) && touchPoint.x<197.00){
        posButton = SeqC;
        pos=2;

    }
    else if(198.00<(touchPoint.x) && touchPoint.x<250.00){
        posButton = SeqD;
        pos=3;

    }
        else if(264.00<(touchPoint.x) && touchPoint.x<314.00){
            posButton = SeqE;
            pos=4;

        }
        else if(317.00<(touchPoint.x) && touchPoint.x<367.00){
            posButton = SeqF;
            pos=5;

        }
        else if(370.00<(touchPoint.x) && touchPoint.x<420.00){
            posButton = SeqG;
            pos=6;

        }
        else if(423.00<(touchPoint.x) && touchPoint.x<473.00){
            posButton = SeqH;
            pos=7;

        }






        else if(488.00<(touchPoint.x) && touchPoint.x<538.00){
            posButton = SeqI;
            pos=8;

        }
        else if(541.00<(touchPoint.x) && touchPoint.x<591.00){
            posButton = SeqJ;
            pos=9;

        }
        else if(594.00<(touchPoint.x) && touchPoint.x<644.00){
            posButton = SeqK;
            pos=10;

        }
        else if(647.00<(touchPoint.x) && touchPoint.x<697.00){
            posButton = SeqL;
            pos=11;

        }

        else if(712.00<(touchPoint.x) && touchPoint.x<762.00){
            posButton = SeqM;
            pos=12;

        }
        else if(765.00<(touchPoint.x) && touchPoint.x<815.00){
            posButton = SeqN;
            pos=13;

        }
        else if(818.00<(touchPoint.x) && touchPoint.x<868.00){
            posButton = SeqO;
            pos=14;

        }
        else if(871.00<(touchPoint.x) && touchPoint.x<921.00){
            posButton = SeqP;
            pos=15;

        }
```

Now do something depending on the button you touched up inside

Other things I did - I created a mask of the original UIButton as a UIImageView that I made unhidden on a touchdragoutside event (and rebidden on the above touchupinside) so that I have a button I can drag

Comment: Why would you not just take and loop through the subviews present in your view and test to see if it was in that rect. That would handle dynamic resizing much more effectively and make your code more robust!

Comment: I just don't know how to do it and I'm not sure it's necessarily applicable for the way I've laid out my app - I tried lots of things, but my understanding just isn't good enough yet and although this way is hacky, it's working and I understand it. I'll re-tick your answer then so as not to throw off other people looking for the solution